# .mouseButtonDown/Up won't work in custom-commands NightwatchJS

Tags: nightwatch.js

When I use .mouseButtonDown/Up in test then it's work, but when I want to add it to my custom command I have typeError "this.move to element(...).mouseButtonDown is not a function"

my custom-command looks like:

```
 resize: function (Xoffset, Yoffset) {
       this.api.pause(1000);
       return this
                .moveToElement("@widget_resize", 5, 5)
                .mouseButtonDown(0)
                .moveToElement("@widgets_container", Xoffset, Yoffset)
                .mouseButtonUp(0);
    }
```

code in test which works:

```
 browser
                .moveToElement("span.react-resizable-handle", 5, 5)
                .mouseButtonDown(0)
                .moveToElement("main.site-container", 1630, 620)
                .mouseButtonUp(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I always pass the client as an argument to any of my custom functions that require any interaction with the browser. I cannot recall why. So, if I am not mistaken, the below should work. I would welcome an explanation as to *why* it works - or why it's a bad idea - by any stackoverflow user:

```
resize: function (client, Xoffset, Yoffset) {
       this.api.pause(1000);
       return
                client.moveToElement("@widget_resize", 5, 5)
                client.mouseButtonDown(0)
                client.moveToElement("@widgets_container", Xoffset, Yoffset)
                client.mouseButtonUp(0);
    }
```

I'm expecting to get downvoted for the reasons why this is not best practice, but I could use the humility and more importantly to better understand this stuff.

Comment: I try to add client as an argument, but it won't help. Now I get different error now "Cannot read property 'moveToelement' of undefined.

Comment: I also try using browser as an argument and it's the same problem. 

I notice that the typeError "this.move to element(...).mouseButtonDown is not a function" only show in Webdriver protocol api(http://nightwatchjs.org/api#protocol). When I use nightwatch api then everything it's fine... So maybe this is some kind of problem here

Answer (score 0):

did you try insert ".pause(500)" ?

```
resize: function (Xoffset, Yoffset) {
   this.api.pause(1000);
   return this
            .moveToElement("@widget_resize", 5, 5)
            .mouseButtonDown(0)
            .pause(500)
            .moveToElement("@widgets_container", Xoffset, Yoffset)
            .mouseButtonUp(0);
}
```

Comment: When I insert pause(500) then I have the same error, so it isn't work... but thanks for your answer